# Error on Help Page

Tags: bug

Near the bottom of [this page](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our Help section, the dissociation of $\ce{HCl}$ in $\ce{H2O}$ is shown.  However a resonance arrow is displayed rather than an equilibrium arrow.  Since we're a chemistry site it seems like we should correct this, but I wasn't sure how to edit the page myself.

Comment: I don't really want to touch this post currently (or ever again for that matter), but this could be considered ***[meta-tag:status-completed]***, as some ages ago the version of the help centre changed significantly (and after that again probably).

Answer (score 5):

I will look into it a bit further, but it appears as though the help page is interpreting the `<=>` symbol as an HTML tag, and is therefore not rendering it properly.

Comment: I fixed it, using HTML entities worked.

Comment: Internet Explorer, ...... ah, never mind. :)))

Comment: Nah, just kidding. I have the latest Chrome and the very section in the very section of help  looks like,..... oh, never mind. :)

Comment: @ManishEarth Just took a look at the page in question and it is not displaying correctly for me. I can see the mathjax code rather than the finished product in both IE11 and Firefox 34.0

Comment: @MARamezani  I don't understand your comments.  Does the equation display correctly in Chrome?  Did it always?

Comment: No, the error you first mentioned was there too. And this second error, "gibberish-like mathjax code"  is currently what is being seen from the 'Chrome' point of view. And about the comments, ignore me. I sometimes get like this. :)

Comment: Somehow it looked fine yesterday. I undid it. SE's XSS filter is tripping on it.